# jquery use radio to click select option

Tags: jquery, html, select, radio-button

this is what I had tried...

I can change the dropdown to show Annually price.. 
but when i click the monthly.. It cannot change back to Monthly price..

I want to run the select onchange function too when the radio button is clicked

how should I fix this?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $(".radio-billing").change(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
            
                $("#inputBillingcycle option").each(function () {
                    var optionValue = $(this).val();
                    if (optionValue == value) {
                        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
                        return;
                    }
                });
        });

});

function someFunction(){
  console.log("function is work!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label>
    <input class="radio-billing" type="radio" name="billingcycle" value="monthly" />
    Monthly price - xxxx
</label>

<label>
    <input class="radio-billing" type="radio" name="billingcycle" value="annually" />
    Annually price - xxxx
</label>


<select name="billingcycle" id="inputBillingcycle" class="form-control select-inline" onchange="someFunction();">

<option value="monthly">                                             Monthly price - xxxx
</option>

<option value="annually">                                             Annually price - xxxx
</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use:

```
$("#inputBillingcycle").val($(this).val()).trigger("change");
```

Because it's a one liner and it's pretty intuitive what it's doing. It sets the value of the select to the same value of your radio buttons.  And **the code will be a lot cleaner**.  Additionally, it makes supporting more than just two radio buttons incredibly fast.  (All you would have to do is add another radio button and then an option with the same value).  Finally, it also invokes the change function for `$("#inputBillingcycle")` when changing the radio buttons as well.

Go ahead and take a look:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $(".radio-billing").change(function () {                
                $("#inputBillingcycle")
                        .val($(this).val())
                        .trigger("change");
        });

});

function someFunction(){
  console.log("function is work!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label>
    <input class="radio-billing" type="radio" name="billingcycle" value="monthly" />
    Monthly price - xxxx
</label>

<label>
    <input class="radio-billing" type="radio" name="billingcycle" value="annually" />
    Annually price - xxxx
</label>


<select name="billingcycle" id="inputBillingcycle" class="form-control select-inline" onchange="someFunction();">

<option value="monthly">                                             Monthly price - xxxx
</option>

<option value="annually">                                             Annually price - xxxx
</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Hey your code is work but how do i run the select onchange function too?

Comment: Updated.  You can now trigger change as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".radio-billing").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("#inputBillingcycle").val(value).trigger('change');
});
```

**Explanation:** You can change the dropdown selection using jquery like:

```
$("#idElement").val('optionValue');
```

or

```
$("#idElement").val('optionValue').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of them get selected so its better to remove the selected first.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $(".radio-billing").change(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
            
                $("#inputBillingcycle option").each(function () {
                    $(this).removeAttr("selected");
                    var optionValue = $(this).val();
                    if (optionValue == value) {
                        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
                        return;
                    }
                });
        });

});

function someFunction(){
  console.log("function is work!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label>
    <input class="radio-billing" type="radio" name="billingcycle" value="monthly" />
    Monthly price - xxxx
</label>

<label>
    <input class="radio-billing" type="radio" name="billingcycle" value="annually" />
    Annually price - xxxx
</label>


<select name="billingcycle" id="inputBillingcycle" class="form-control select-inline" onchange="someFunction();">

<option value="monthly">                                             Monthly price - xxxx
</option>

<option value="annually">                                             Annually price - xxxx
</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are much easier way to handle this situation but this will fix your current code. You were not removing the "selected" attribute from each of the options. So after selecting both of the radio buttons that would result in both of the objects having the "selected" attribute.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $(".radio-billing").change(function () {

    var value = $(this).val();

    $("#inputBillingcycle option").each(function () {

      $(this).removeAttr("selected");

      if ($(this).val() == value) {

        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");

      }

    });

  });

});
```

See jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/avocahose15/m36b861g/